# Understanding c function in assembly

Tags: assembly, intel

I am trying to learn how to understand c functions in assembler. I compiled the following c program using "gcc code.c -m32 -o code -S -fno-stack-protector"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function( int a, int b, int c )
{
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
}

void main()
{
   function( 1, 2, 3 );
}
```

The assember output was the following:

```
        .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _function
    .align  4, 0x90
_function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $28, %esp
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    movl    %edx, -4(%ebp)
    movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    addl    $28, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    movl    $2, 4(%esp)
    movl    $3, 8(%esp)
    call    _function
    addl    $24, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret


.subsections_via_symbols
```

The esp and ebp registers cannot be equal because the offsets that define int a,b,c are different in _main and _function.  What line subtracts 4 from ebp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to subtract 4 anywhere as it is the return adress that (given a 32-bit architecture) will consume the top 4 bytes on the stack.

Thus the difference of $4 when referring to the elements on the stack. The return adress hasn't been pushed *before* the `call` instruction Thus offsets $0 $4 and $8 are fine in main:

```
movl    $1, (%esp)
movl    $2, 4(%esp)
movl    $3, 8(%esp)
```

Executing:

```
call    _function
```

in main will push the contents of eip (the return adress) on the stack thus increasing esp by 4.

In function as the return adress (consuming 4 bytes) will be on top of the stack the correct offsets are -$4, -$8 and -$12 this are exactly the values used in your function:

```
movl    %edx, -4(%ebp)
movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
```

Comment: It's the `call` instruction that automatically will push the return adress on the stack and increase esp by 4. I'll add that to the answer to make things clear.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function usually works like this:

1) Outside the function, the arguments are pushed onto the stack

```
subl    $24, %esp
movl    $1, (%esp)
movl    $2, 4(%esp)
movl    $3, 8(%esp)
```

2) Inside the function, space is allocated on the stack to hold the arguments and the local variables.

subl    $28, %esp

In this case you have 3 ints and 15 chars, for a total of 27 bytes; this is aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

3) Arguments are then copied into the local stack space.

```
movl    16(%ebp), %eax
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
movl    8(%ebp), %edx
movl    %edx, -4(%ebp)
movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
```

Here, 16(%ebp) and friends are the addresses of the arguments pushed outside, and -4(%ebp) are the addresses in the newly allocated stack space into which those values are being copied.